# Error al ejecutar la configuración del webpack

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, webpack

Cada vez que intento generar la carpeta dist (npm run build) con el archivo de configuración de webpack me arroja un error en consola y no genera correctamente el archivo index.html, este es el error que me arroja la consola: 
ERROR in Error: Child compilation failed:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dist/main.js' in '/home/arturo/Desktop/Javascript/03-Webpack/src':
Error: Can't resolve '../dist/main.js' in '/home/arturo/Desktop/Javascript/03-Webpack/src'
Mi configuración del webpack y este es el archivo index.html que se genera en la carpeta dist con errores: 
Alguna solución 
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boehc.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Inserto el codigo del archivo webpack.config.js
```

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 

module.exports = {

    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        }),
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quería aclarar que ya encontré una solución al error, pues en la versión 1.0.0 del html-loader, ahora es un poquito diferente, miren:

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
 
 
module.exports = {
 
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    attributes: false,
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        }),
    ]
 
    
}
```

Para los que les de este error, esta es la solución!

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada